# Send recieving messages to email when app is not active

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

In my project, I want to send all receiving messages to an `email address`. I successfully did that when the `app` is open. but when the `app` is closed, I can't send the`mail`.
how to detect the message is received when the `app` is closed.
I used the worker for the email sending.
Also, I want to get the message data to the worker class to send the email.

**Worker Class**

```
public class MessageSenderWorker extends Worker {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        try {
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("emailaddredd",
                            "password");
                    try {
                        sender.sendMail("datafrom mesaage", "datafrom mesaage",
                                "emailaddress", "emailaddress");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            return Result.SUCCESS;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Result.FAILURE;
        }

    }
}
```

My Broadcast Reciever

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static MessageListener mListener;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
    for(int i=0; i<pdus.length; i++){
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String message = "Sender : " + smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()
                + "Email From: " + smsMessage.getEmailFrom()
                + "Emal Body: " + smsMessage.getEmailBody()
                + "Display message body: " + smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody()
                + "Time in millisecond: " + smsMessage.getTimestampMillis()
                + "Message: " + smsMessage.getMessageBody();
        mListener.messageReceived(message);

        NotificationWorker notificationWorker = new NotificationWorker();
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder dataCheckBuilder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(notificationWorker.getClass(), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setConstraints(networkConstraints());
        PeriodicWorkRequest dataCheckWork = dataCheckBuilder.build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(dataCheckWork);

    }
}
```

Comment: "App is closed" - there are two different taks: for active phone and for sleep phone (need to wake up the phone etc).

Comment: @Style-7 I meant by "APP is closed" is, whenever to receive a message to the phone. (if the app is running, in the background, removed from recent apps and the phone screen is on/off)

Answer (score 0):

If user turn screen OFF then you must use AlarmManager only (based on my practise) no more than 1 time in 30 minutes. For example you can use custom Broadcast Reciever and call it by AlarmManager. Custom Broadcast Reciever set new Alarm etc. Also you have to create Boot Broadcast Reciever to start Alarm.

Comment: I am already using the Worker, so there is no need of AlarmManager, right?

Comment: No, a Worker can not "wake up deice".

Answer (score 0):

To "wake up" a device, because of Doze Mode and app stand-by, the only reliable (and battery-friendly) is to use a high priority Firebase Cloud Message ([FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)).

Your app can then handle this message retrieving the email you sent. An option there is that, when you receive the FCM, you enqueue a worker that will then download the message/email.

Everything else will be impacted by Doze Mode and other battery optimization systems in Android. Also, using an FCM is the most battery friendly solution for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Workers already run on a background thread - you shouldn't create your own inside them.  They're also for synchronous work - meaning by the time you return a result, your work should have been completed.  Take out all the "new Thread" code and put the contents of the Thread directly in the Worker.  You'll also want to read this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading